# Batch file to create new folder in current directory with a name from the clipboard

Tags: batch-file, directory, clipboard

I am currently in the process on downloading a lot of individually grouped files. Each group has its own name based on the topic.

Currently this is what I am doing,

1. Highlighting text to copy a topic name.
2. Right clicking in whatever directory I am in and creating a new folder.
3. Pasting to name the new folder.

What I want to do is create a batch file that does this, and then I will add it in my explorer contextual window and also create a keyboard shortcut for the batch file.

Just like the subject says I would like to:

create a Batch file that will create a new folder in the current directory I am working in. The name of the folder should be from the clipboard.

this is new to me but I currently understand

`mkdir` for a new folder
and I believe `%clipboard%` for clipboard
and `%cd%` for the current directory.

Comment: I don't believe you can access the clipboard from a batch file. You have two options: 1) Parse the text file containing the folder names within the batch file and create the folders that way; 2) use Powershell, where you may have access to the clipboard. WARNING: The clipboard is a global, single instance system resource. If you cut/copy anything while the Powershell script is running, you _may_ replace whatever the script put on the clipboard. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There are third party free tools to read the clipboard - but the current directory in an explorer window isn't exposed by any means I know of - this means you can't programmatically create a folder in the same place you are manipulating it in an explorer window.

You can however use the free `autohotkey` to press keys, click, and copy to the clipboard, paste etc from a simple hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

For the contextual menu integration, probably superuser.com is a better place

For the folder creation from clipboard

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: Where to create the folder should come from contextual menu as parameter
    if "%~1"=="" exit /b 1
    if not exist "%~1" exit /b 1

    :: 1 retrieve name from clipboard (if the clipboard contains text)
    :: 2 ensure the target folder path ends with a backslash
    :: 3 create the folder

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (
        `mshta "javascript:var data;try{data=window.clipboardData.getData('Text');}catch(e){};new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(data?data:'');close();"`
    ) do for /d %%b in ("%~f1\") do (
        if not exist "%%~fb%%a" (
            md "%%~fb%%a"
        ) else (
            echo(%%~fb%%a exists
            pause
        )
    )
```

This uses `mshta.exe` (that is part of windows) to retrieve the data from clipboard using javascript code.